# How to add new redirection on wordpress site

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I have created new website `https://example1.com/` and I have one old site `https://example.com/`. We have a customer support ticket portal and that portal URL is `https://support.example.com/`. Now I have changed the support portal URL into `https://support.example1.com/` Now I want to add redirection for following conditions on `.htaccess`.

1. Redirect `https://support.example.com/` to `https://support.example1.com/`
2. Redirect `https://support.example.com/a/ticket/124` into `https://support.example1.com/a/ticket/124`
3. Redirect `https://support.example.com/ticket/124` into `https://support.example1.com/ticket/124`

How can I achieve this anyone knows the solution for this one?

Comment: To clarify, you only want to redirect the `support` subdomain on HTTP only? You don't want to redirect the domain apex (your new site) and you don't wish to redirect to HTTPS?

Comment: @MrWhite want to redirect into https i just given the example

Comment: @MrWhite i edited my question

Comment: You only want those 3 URLs redirected? And the `support` subdomain also points to your wp installation (is this also handled by wp)?

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd are example there will be ticket number will change there is lot of tickets we need to redirect that for all tickets for 2nd and 3rd

Answer (score 1):

To redirect just those 3 URLs (with variable *ticket number*) on the `support` subdomain then you can do something like the following *before* the WordPress front-controller (assuming the `support` subdomain resolves to the same place and is probably handled by WP) using mod_rewrite, in the root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^support\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?:a/)?ticket/\d+)?$ https://support.example1.com/$0 [R=302,L]
```

Change to a 301 (permanent) redirect only when you are sure it's working OK.

Note that this doesn't specifically redirect HTTP to HTTPS.